# How to add edition to ebook title when saving ebook to disk using Calibre?

Tags: ebook, calibre

I want to include the edition, e.g., `(4th ed)`, in the file names of my ebooks. How can I do this in Calibre?

Comment: Right click - Edit Metadata then edit the title?

Comment: And there is no automatic way to do this?

Comment: It doesn't seem so as the Metadata does not have edition for a start...

Comment: Then maybe it is the best to add custom column "editions", in which I would place the values?

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked in 2014. Now, in 2019, there does exist a sophisticated feature to customize a book's saved file name and even directory path.

In your case, since `edition` may not be a default metadata field (it isn't in my version), this may be a two-step process.

First, look under `preferences` for `add your own columns` and create a new metadata element `edition`. Calibre may insist on re-loading in order to apply the changes.

Then, also under `preferences`, look for the section `saving books to disk`, and see that you are provided with the opportunity to create what they call a "template" to customize the file and directory name by any combination of metadata. In your case, you can insert your new custom metadata field using the format string `{#edition}`, so an example template might be `{author}_-_{title}_{#edition}`.